# Homomorphism from $Q_8$ to $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-homomorphism

From Dummit and Foote *Abstract Algebra*, 1.6.26.

> Define the map $\varphi$ from $Q_8$ to $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ defined on the generators by 
>   $$ \varphi(i) =  
> \begin{bmatrix}
>    \sqrt{-1}        & 0 \\      0       & -\sqrt{-1}   \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> \quad \text{and} \quad
> \varphi(j) =  
> \begin{bmatrix}
>    0  & -1 \\    1   &0   \\
> \end{bmatrix} .$$
>   Prove that this map extends to a homomorphism.

Does this mean prove $\varphi$ is a homomorphism on $Q_8$?

If so, then I can show

$$\quad \varphi(ij) = \varphi(i)\varphi(j), \quad \varphi(ii) = \varphi(i)\varphi(i), \quad \text{and} \quad \varphi(jj) = \varphi(j)\varphi(j),$$
which shows $\varphi$ is a homomorphism on the generators.
I think that automatically makes it a homomorphism on $Q_8$, since $i,j$ generate $Q_8$.

Is that correct?

Comment: $Q_8$ is defined by the relations $(-1)^2=1, i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$ with $k=ij$, so to be safe you should check all those relations. After applying $\varphi$ that is.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the corrections! However, since $Q_8$ is generated by $i$ and $j$, shouldn't it suffice to check only the relations involving only the generators?

Comment: Yes, if you check all of them. I think that a minimal set of relations (to define $Q_8$) is $i^2=j^2=-1$ (which also defined the element $-1\in Q_8$, $(-1)^2=1$, $ji=-ij$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes . . . Almost.

You need to show $\phi(ji)=\phi(j)\phi(i)$, since $ij=k\neq -k=ji$.

But you could say that $-k$ is a scalar multiple of $k$, so your $\phi(ij)=\phi(i)\phi(j)$ would suffice.

Comment: Is that because I haven't shown that $\varphi (xy) = \varphi(x)\varphi(y)$ for arbitrary $x,y \in Q_8$?  so instead I need to show that all the relations involving the generators $i,j$ hold?

Comment: I believe so, yes, @Jess.

Comment: Except, I haven't explicity stated that $\phi(ii) = \phi(-1)$, do I need to do that also?

Comment: I suppose not, @Jess. I'm nitpicking in this answer really. It's more helpful than a simple yes/no answer.

Comment: To clarify, it suffices to show that it's an homomorpism on the generators of $Q_8$, and to do so, for completeness, one must consider $\phi(ji)$ too because $i$ and $j$ do not commute.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks

Comment: Hmm. The element $-1$ of the group $Q_8$ does not act as a scalar on all the representations of $Q_8$. Being central, it does act as a scalar on all the *irreducible* representations. But there are homomorphisms from $Q_8$ to $GL_3(\Bbb{C})$ such that $-1$ of $Q_8$ does not get mapped to a scalar matrix.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you, @JyrkiLahtonen.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen could you please explain why $-1$ acting like a scalar on irreducible representations isn't enough?

Comment: @Jess This is an irreducible representation, so here it will act as a scalar. Furthermore, that scalar happens to be $-1$. There are also homomorphisms from $Q_8$ to $GL_1(\Bbb{C})$ (necessarily irreducible), where $-1\in Q_8$ acts as scalar $+1$. Basically because $i\mapsto \pm1_{\Bbb{C}}$, $j\mapsto\pm1_{\Bbb{C}}$ define homomorphisms for all sign combinations.

Comment: But we also have a homomorphism to $GL_3(\Bbb{C})$ like
$$i\mapsto\pmatrix{-1&0&0\cr0&i&0\cr0&0&-i\cr}, j\mapsto\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&0&-1\cr0&1&0\cr},$$ when
$$-1=i^2=j^2\mapsto\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&-1&0\cr0&0&-1\cr}.$$ A bit contrived, but possible. That 3-dimensional representation is not irreducible. It is the sum of 1-d and 2-d reps, and the different scalars $-1\in Q_8$ acts by show up on the diagonal accordingly.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution online.

$Q_8$ can be expressed as $\{i,j \; | i^4=1, i^2=j^2, ji=ij^{-1} \} $.

So, we need to prove that $\varphi(i)$ and  $\varphi(j)$ satisfy these relations. Since they do, we can conclude $\varphi$ is a homomorphism from $Q_8$ to $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.